# why is this SQL query not returning the expected result?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am a new to the SQL Server and I am trying to understand and know why the following query is not returning the data:

```
SELECT Port,Server
FROM (
      SELECT FieldName,FieldValue
    FROM tblConstants 
    WHERE FuncName='Mail' and IsActive=1) d
pivot (
       max(FieldValue)
       for FieldName in (Port,Server)
    ) piv;
```

The first part of the query that includes the next two lines is working properly and returns the desired values:

```
SELECT FieldName,FieldValue
        FROM tblConstants 
        WHERE FuncName='Mail' and IsActive=1
```

However, after combining these two lines with the second part, the query doesn't return any values and I don't know why.

**Could you please explain to me why it is not returning the data?**

UPDATED:
The desired result is:

```
Port --------------- Server
50   --------------- testserver.company.com
```

Comment: Replace the Port,Server in "for FieldName in (Port,Server)" with actual port and server values and see what happens. Also, run your query all the way up to the PIVOT and see what happens.

Comment: SELECT Port,Server.... from SELECT FieldName,FieldValue....

Comment: Change it to "for FieldName in ([port], [server])"

Comment: There's no data  or expected results. Are you making the question intentionally difficult to answer?

Comment: The structure of your question isn't conducive to getting a lot of helpful answers. Have a look here and consider editing your question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What values are returned from the first part?  Do you see any rows where the FieldName is 'Port' or 'Server'?

Comment: Guys, sorry for ambiguity in my question, but I am new here in StackOverFlow and I am seeking your help in this question. Please see the updates in my question.

Comment: Can you give us an example of what the source data (ie that in tblConstants) looks like?

Comment: Try this as a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: What version of SQL? When I test on sqlfiddle, it works just fine.

Comment: @Shawn, I am using SQL Server 2012

Comment: After the above changes, does your query still return no results? I ran the query on SQL Fiddle, and it worked, though not as intended for multiple results.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because your example DB schema currently doesn't have a way to relate a Port row to a ServerName row, so your `PIVOT` is returning the literal `max()` value for each column. And since you were only looking at one row of data, with multiple rows, your `PIVOT` will only return the actual `max` row of each `FieldValue` record. You need to add another row that will be unique to each "grouping" of results that relates the `Port` to the `Server`.

I've also aliased the query so you can see where the different data points are coming from in the query. That may help with understanding the flow of a `PIVOT`.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2f1384/2)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE tblConstants (
    FieldName varchar(100)
  , FieldValue varchar(100)
  , FuncName varchar(100)
  , isActive bit
  , relatedField varchar(10));

/* Create "4" rows of data to PIVOT */
INSERT INTO tblConstants (FieldName, FieldValue, FuncName, isActive, relatedField)
VALUES 
    ('Port', 'q','Mail',1, 'group1')
  , ('Server','testserver.company.com','Mail',1, 'group1') 
  , ('Port', 'b','Mail',1, 'group2')
  , ('Server','testserver2.company.com','Mail',1, 'group2') 
  , ('Port', 'd','Mail',1, 'group3')
  , ('Server','testserver3.company.com','Mail',1, 'group3') 
  , ('Port', 'a','Mail',1, 'group4')
  , ('Server','testserver4.company.com','Mail',1, 'group4')
;
```

**Base Query**: *This query is the base data we are working with.*

```
SELECT 
    t.FieldName
  , t.FieldValue
  , t.relatedField /* This is our relation row */
FROM tblConstants t
WHERE t.FuncName='Mail' and t.IsActive=1
ORDER BY relatedField, FieldName, FieldValue
```

**[Which Gives Us](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2f1384/2/0)**:

```
| FieldName |              FieldValue | relatedField |
|-----------|-------------------------|--------------|
|      Port |                       q |       group1 |
|    Server |  testserver.company.com |       group1 |
|      Port |                       b |       group2 |
|    Server | testserver2.company.com |       group2 |
|      Port |                       d |       group3 |
|    Server | testserver3.company.com |       group3 |
|      Port |                       a |       group4 |
|    Server | testserver4.company.com |       group4 |
```

Note that `relatedField` will give us a value that is unique for each group of related `FieldValue`s.

**Full PIVOTed Query**:

```
SELECT piv.Port, piv.Server
FROM (
    SELECT 
        t.FieldName
      , t.FieldValue
      , t.relatedField /* This is our relation row */
    FROM tblConstants t
    WHERE t.FuncName='Mail' and t.IsActive=1
) d
pivot (
       max(d.FieldValue)
       for d.FieldName in (Server,Port)
) piv
```

**[Final Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2f1384/2/1)**:

```
| Port |                  Server |
|------|-------------------------|
|    q |  testserver.company.com |
|    b | testserver2.company.com |
|    d | testserver3.company.com |
|    a | testserver4.company.com |
```

We are `PIVOT`ing on the `FieldName`, and since we aggregate, we have to have something that sets the individual groups apart to give a valid aggregation of the group, even though we don't specify that column in the final output (we could `SELECT` `relatedGroup` from the `piv` resultset if we wanted to).